# Vertically aligning multiple lines of text to a single line

Tags: alignment, cv

I am writing my resume and would like to align my contact information‌ —in this case an email and phone number— to my name. In effect, I'd have one big block of text left-aligned to the page, and at the same vertical level two lines of text right-aligned to the page, like so:

[image]

My current attempt looks like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{bbding}
    \usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
    \begin{document}

{\fontsize{1.618em}{1.618em} John Doe}
\hfill
{\fontsize{0.75em}{1em} \Envelope \hspace{2mm} - example@sharklasers.com }
\linebreak
\hfill
{\fontsize{0.75em}{1em} \Phone \hspace{2mm} - (555) 555-5555 }

\end{document}
```

Which renders like so:

[image]

The problems is that the phone number is getting pushed to the next line. Which makes sense, when I think about it, but I'm not sure how I can link the phone number and email together, to be pushed over with `hfill` (assuming there isn't a better way to do it).

Secondly, I think the Unicode is slightly misaligned, which may be due to my font settings (but at this point I'm not sure what I should look at changing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this. Using better icon package `fontawesome5`. And put the text in two `parbox` with fixed width and bottom aligned. If you have longer text on the right, you need adjust the width of the `\parbox`(e.g. `\parbox[b]{5cm}{text...}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage[fixed]{fontawesome5}% better icon package
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent\parbox[b]{2.3cm}{\fontsize{1.618em}{1.618em}\selectfont John Doe}
\hfill
\parbox[b]{3.7cm}{\fontsize{0.75em}{1em}\selectfont%
\faEnvelope\space example@sharklasers.com\par
\faPhone\space (555) 555-5555\par
\faHome\space 22 Street, CA\par
}
\hrule\vskip10pt

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]